# Laundromat in walking-distance of CDG Airport hotel?

Tags: cdg, laundry

We are staying at the CDG Hilton, however they do not have a laundromat.  Is there a laundromat or coin machines in a nearby hotel?  Ideally something within walking distance

UPDATE: I used Gonesse's "Top Lavenderie" to quickly launder clothing. If there is a site that is closer / on the airport that would be ideal

Comment: I’m quite surprised, the Hotels.com app says no for hotels (closest hotel with washing machine 20 km away), and Accor don’t mention it either for any of their numerous hotels in the area. You may want to ask at the reception desk if you hotels and the ones nearby (like the Ibis or Ibis Styles just around the corner), though I’m not sure they will accept outside visitors to use those facilities if they have any. Can’t find a public one in the area either. They probably want you to use their laundry service…

Comment: It seems to me (as a French native going to hotels a few nights a year) that it is very uncommon in France to have laundromat inside a hotel. Either they offer an expensive laundry service, either they expect you to go to some _laverie libre-service_. There doesn't seem to be any in the airport vicinity.

Comment: Most people won’t stay a long time at CDG, so guest laundromats will be thin on the ground there sad to say. Last month I stayed in a French hotel with a laundromat for the guests, but it was in a seaside resort town with mostly long term (week or more) guests.

Answer (score 4):

The French term is *laverie automatique*.

I can't find a mention of a laundromat on the [Paris airports website](https://www.parisaeroport.fr/). I expect that many hotels have a laundry service, but only an expensive one where they wash things for you. Only hostels tend to have a washing machine you can use, and even that may not be the case in an urban environment: they might expect you to go to a laundromat.

Searching for [laundromats on Google Maps](https://www.google.fr/maps/search/laverie+automatique/@49.0102926,2.4750273,12z/data=!3m1!4b1?entry=ttu), you can see that they are in the towns near the airport, none in the airport itself. I would expect Google Maps to find these businesses. So there's no walkable option. You'll have to take a bus or train. By train, there's one not far from Sevran-Beaudottes, and one very close to Aulnay-sous-Bois. By bus, I don't know what's the most convenient. Maybe [line 95-2](https://me-deplacer.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/en/timetables/bus/line%3AIDFM%3AC00265?direction=-1&line&transporter) to [Mairie de Le Thillay](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Mairie/@49.0029067,2.4707779,16.82z/data=!4m9!1m2!2m1!1smairie!3m5!1s0x47e6154d1bf18ff3:0x5a796e1e25a52070!8m2!3d49.00264!4d2.47155!16s%2Fg%2F11r0h7xj75?entry=ttu), there's a laundromat just down the street.

Note that almost all laundromats are only open during the day, and coins may be required for payment.